# Setting ACL of objects based on Parse Relation field

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have two Parse Classes **Group** and **Post**.
**Group** have a parse relation field **people** (users, that are in this group) and **Post** have a pointer field **group** (which group, this post belong to).

When someone create a group, he/she add his friends to this group that are being saved in "people" field.

Everybody who is in the people relation can post in the group.

I have some questions about setting ACL on post and group object.

1. When a group object is being saved. How to set its acl based on the "people" (parse relation field) in beforeSave (I don't want to set ACL on client side) ?
2. When some one post in the group the acl of the post object should also be based on the parse relation field "people" from "Group" class. **Note that i want that acl of the post object should be dynamic in a way that when someone joined group later, he/she should be able to see previous posts from his/her joined date

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(POST, function(request, response){
 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
 
 var post = request.object;
 var owner = post.get("owner");
 var community = post.get("group")
 var draft = post.get("draft");
 
 if (!owner || !draft || !community) return response.error(PARAMETERS_NOT_FOUND);
 if (draft.length <1) return response.error(FIELD_SIZE_LIMIT_NOT_ENOUGH)

 var community = validateCommunity(community.id);
 if (!community) return response.error(FAKE_COMMUNITY); 
  
    var people_to_share = community.relation("people");
    
    var acl = new Parse.ACL();
    acl.setWriteAccess(owner, true);
    acl.setReadAccess(owner, true);
  
    // Now here i want to set the acl of post for all people_to_share .... And that is working good ... but the problem is when i add new person in community (people field) .... I have to do set acl for him in every post of community. 
 
post.setACL(acl);
response.success();

});
```

Comment: You should provide some code that someone can have a look at to provide you with a little more detailed help - as it stands you are asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: Ok. i  have given the code as well

Comment: You should be using roles

Comment: @Wain Yes i solved using role. Thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I have solved this Issue using a common role. 
I created a role for every group and saved it in the Group Class as a pointer. Whenever a new person is added to group. I give him read access to that group's role. And on removing person from that group. I remove his read access.

Similarly, When new post is created, I just set post's acl to that group's role. It is good dynamic way.